# Query Mongodb collection over a date range

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection with below documents:

```
var interactions = [ { _id: 54ed77eec55b18101e82f205,
    email: 'customercare@tikona.in',
    contactCompanyName: 'tikona',
    contactFullName: 'Customercare',
    contactValue: 0,
    "interactionDate": "2016-03-30T08:28:58.000Z",
},
{ _id: 54ed77eec55b18101e82f205,
    email: 'inbox@google.com',
    contactCompanyName: 'google',
    contactFullName: 'inbox',
    contactValue: 0,
    "interactionDate": "2016-03-30T08:28:58.000Z",
},
{ _id: 54ed77eec55b18101e82f205,
    email: 'nazar@zinavo.com',
    contactCompanyName: 'zinavo',
    contactFullName: 'nazar',
    contactValue: 0,
    "interactionDate": "2016-03-25T08:28:58.000Z",
},
    { _id: 54ed77eec55b18101e82f205,
        email: 'nazar@zinavo.com',
        contactCompanyName: 'zinavo',
        contactFullName: 'nazar',
        contactValue: 0,
        "interactionDate": "2016-03-26T08:28:58.000Z",
    },
    { _id: 54ed77eec55b18101e82f205,
        email: 'nazar@zinavo.com',
        contactCompanyName: 'zinavo',
        contactFullName: 'nazar',
        contactValue: 0,
        "interactionDate": "2016-03-13T08:28:58.000Z",
    },
    { _id: 54ed77eec55b18101e82f205,
        email: 'inbox@google.com',
        contactCompanyName: 'google',
        contactFullName: 'inbox',
        contactValue: 0,
        "interactionDate": "2016-04-06T08:28:58.000Z",
    },
    { _id: 54ed77eec55b18101e82f205,
        email: 'nazar@zinavo.com',
        contactCompanyName: 'zinavo',
        contactFullName: 'nazar',
        contactValue: 0,
        "interactionDate": "2016-04-03T08:28:58.000Z",
    }]
```

How do I query this collection such that the `interactionDate` is greater than or equal to past 60 days but lesser than or equal to past 30 days. i.e I need to find and count the documents from 12 Feb 2016 till 12 March 2016 and then from 12 March 2016 till 12 April 2016, and then find the difference between the count of interactions between these two date ranges.

**Techniques I tried**

Fetch interactions for both the date ranges. e.g.

```
{ '$gte': Fri Feb 12 2016 11:29:29 GMT+0530 (IST),
  '$lte': Tue March 12 2016 11:29:29 GMT+0530 (IST) }
```

and then run a second query:

```
{ '$gte': Fri Marc 12 2016 11:29:29 GMT+0530 (IST),
  '$lte': Tue Apr 12 2016 11:29:29 GMT+0530 (IST) }
```

and then, for each email, subtract the interactions count.

Aggregation query:

```
{
    $match:{
        {"interactions.email":{$in:emailArr}}}
},
{
    $group:{
        _id: "$interactions.email",
            count: { $sum: 1}
    }
},
{
    $sort: {"count" : -1}
},
{
    $project:{
        email: "$_id",
            interactionCount
    :
        "$count",
            _id
    :
        0,
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered storing your dates in epoch time?

Comment: I haven't given it a thought. But how should the epoch time help me here?

Comment: Are the email ids in sample data real ? You may not want to expose customer email addresses.

Comment: They are not real data. They are just newsletter email Ids :-)

Comment: Your aggregate operation suggests that there is an embedded field `interactions.email` in your documents but the sample documents you have above say otherwise, can you clarify on that?

Comment: @chridam- yes, I put the documents in an array. I have a document which has an embedded array "interactions". Apologies for not being succinct. I edited the question.

Comment: No worries. So the above is a sample **document** with an array field `interactions` that has embedded documents, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.